# Read line from text file and assign variable automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am generating a PDF from a TXT HTML file using `itextsharp`. I am reading from a file line by line.  This line is showing an invalid path:

```
"<td style='width: 393px;' colspan='4' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;<img src='" + Server.MapPath("~/images/diblack.png") + "' alt='System' width='100' height='50' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>"
```

But this is showing the correct image:

```
sb.Append("<td style='width: 393px;' colspan='4' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;<img src='" + Server.MapPath("~/images/diblack.png") + "' alt='System' width='100' height='50' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>");
```

How I can read the line and assign the image as per requirement?

Comment: You are reading from a static HTML file? How can Server.MapPath (a server-side operation) work?

Comment: dear i am reading static html  file and creating pdf i have written Server.MapPath in html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Server.MapPath("~/images/diblack.png")
```

is C# code. For a library that expects **HTML** there is *no* reason to evaluate C# within that HTML code. And the the part within the `src` attribute is not a valid path, since it's literally `" + Server.MapPath("~/images/diblack.png") + "`.

On the other hand, when you write the line

```
"<td style='width: 393px;' colspan='4' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;<img src='" + Server.MapPath("~/images/diblack.png") + "' alt='System' width='100' height='50' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>"
```

in code it's naturally interpreted as C# and the `Server.MapPath(...)` is evaluated correctly.

**EDIT**

It's possible to compile and evaluate C# code on the fly with the `CSharpCodeProvider` (see [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/codedom-calculator-evaluating-C-Sharp-math-expressions-dynamica/) or [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9019/Compiling-and-Executing-Code-at-Runtime) for example). It's not hard to achieve, but still a bit work. If you have the budget, you could buy a library that faciliates the code to compile and evaluate C# code from a string (see [here](https://eval-expression.net/) for example - I'm not affiliated with the vendor).

EDIT 2:

While the method presented in the first edit qould work, it's certainly easier to add some kind of placeholders to your HTML code, e.g.

```
<td style='width: 393px;' colspan='4' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;<img src='!SERVER_PATH[~/images/diblack.png]' alt='System' width='100' height='50' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

After reading the line you can easily replace the placeholder with a regular expression

```
var line = ReadLine();
var matches  = Regex.Matches(line, "!SERVER_PATH\\[([\\~a-z\\.\\/]+)\\]");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    line = line.Replace(match.Value, Server.MapPath(match.Groups[1].Value));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much dear. i think batter way is put img src='image1' and               
line = line.Replace("image1", Server.MapPath("~/images/diblack.png"));

Comment: This is another possibility, if that suffices for you. Please see my second edit. This is a bit more flexible, though.

Comment: The code should work in that case, too. If there are several placeholders with the same text, all of them will be replaced with the first call to `Replace`, hence there is headroom for optimization, since we would not have to call `Replace` multiple times. If there are different placeholders, all of them should be replaced correctly. You should move the code to fill the placeholders to another class and unit-test it separately to be sure it does what you expect it to.